# error in output of long number multiplication

Tags: c

I have written a code in c for long number multiplication but output is not being displayed on the IDE. Please can you point out the error in the given code. Also which language is more efficient for solving these type of problems?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 10000
void main()
{
    char ac[MAX];
    char bc[MAX];
    int a[MAX],b[MAX];
    int mul[MAX];
    int c[MAX];
    int temp[MAX];
    int la,lb;
    int i,j,k=0,x=0,y;
    long int r=0;
    long int sum = 0;
    la=strlen(ac)-1;
    lb=strlen(bc)-1;
    printf("Enter the first number : ");
    scanf("%s",ac);
    printf("Enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%s",bc);

    for(i=0;i<=la;i++){
        a[i] = ac[i] - 48;
    }

    for(i=0;i<=lb;i++){
        b[i] = bc[i] - 48;
    }

    for(i=lb;i>=0;i--){
        r=0;
        for(j=la;j>=0;j--){
            temp[k++] = (b[i]*a[j] + r)%10;
            r = (b[i]*a[j]+r)/10;
        }
        temp[k++] = r;
        x++;
        for(y = 0;y<x;y++){
            temp[k++] = 0;
        }
    }
    k=0;
    r=0;
    for(i=0;i<la+lb+2;i++)
        {
            sum =0;
            y=0;
            for(j=1;j<=lb+1;j++){
                if(i <= la+j){
                    sum = sum + temp[y+i];
                }
                y += j + la + 1 ;
            }
            c[k++] = (sum+r) %10;
            r = (sum+r)/10;
        }
    if (r==1)
        {
            c[k]=r;
        }
    j=0;
    for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--){
        mul[j++]=c[i];

    }

    for(i=0;i<j;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",mul[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: There are libraries for arbitrary precision math.

Comment: Python and Lisp have built-in arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: @barmar thanks for the info. but i would be glad if you help me out with the error.

Comment: You asked which languages can do this.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger so you can see where the incorrect results are coming from?

Comment: @Barmar actually i am new to coding and pretty unaware about debugging. if you could do this for me i would be thankful to you.

Comment: @SaadAnwar:  Then it's your chance to learn to do it.  People here are not your employees and even if they learn something from the experience, you won't.  Note that the BC library does the job much better than your code: https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_node/bc_toc.html#TOC18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate the length of the input strings before assigning the strings:

```
la=strlen(ac)-1;
lb=strlen(bc)-1;
printf("Enter the first number : ");
scanf("%s",ac);
printf("Enter the second number : ");
scanf("%s",bc);
```

If you instead do it the other way around the program actually does something:

```
printf("Enter the first number : ");
scanf("%s",ac);
printf("Enter the second number : ");
scanf("%s",bc);
la=strlen(ac)-1;
lb=strlen(bc)-1;
```

Your second problem is in the last part of your code:

```
for(i=0;i<j;j++)
    {
        printf("%d",mul[i]);
    }
```

You're incrementing j instead of i, it should be:

```
for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",mul[i]);
    }
```

Another little thing, this isn't really clear what it does to the uninitiated:

```
a[i] = ac[i] - 48;
```

if you write it like this it's easier to understand:

```
a[i] = ac[i] - '0';
```

Comment: Even the "initiated" prefer `- '0'` -- magic numbers are **bad**.

Answer (score 0):

Use remove those la and l assignment and put it after scanning the strings like below.

```
printf("Enter the first number : ");
scanf("%s",ac);
printf("Enter the second number : ");
scanf("%s",bc);

la=strlen(ac)-1; 
lb=strlen(bc)-1;

for(i=0;i<=la;i++){
        a[i] = ac[i] - 48;
}

for(i=0;i<=lb;i++){
        b[i] = bc[i] - 48;
}
```

Even in the last part of your code there is an error.Inside the loop you have used `for(i=0;i<j;j++)` replace it with `for(i=0;i<j;i++)`.

I would also suggest you to change the size of temp array to 2*MAX+2.Because suppose somebody enters a number of 8000 digits then temp wont be able to store these many digits if the size is restricted to MAX only.

you can use java and python languages for doing same. In Java there is separate class known as BigInteger.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger b1,b2,b3;
String num1,num2; 

System.out.println("Enter the first integer");
num1=sc.next();

System.out.println("Enter the second integer");
num2=sc.next();

b1=new BigInteger(num1);
b2=new BigInteger(num2);
b3=b1.multiply(b2);

System.out.println("The product of "+b1+" and "+b2+" is "+b3);
```

Comment: The -1 on the strlen() should be there, he's using <= in the comparison part of the for loop.